Usage of あたり to mean “the fact that”
I can kind of guess what it’s trying to say from context, it seems to mean something like “the fact that”;
but I can’t seem to find formal explanation in my grammar books to explain this usage of あたり, any help would be greatly appreciated. Examples:

部長にかみつくあたり、けっこう気が強い

そんなこと言いつつ、こうやって付き合ってくれるあたり、やっぱり仲間ということでしょうか


